# How to prevent a default event in regards of Ajax result

Tags: jquery

I have a button that performs two duties, one is part of a theme, another is an ajax call.

This is the default behavior:

```
$(".next").click(function () {
    if (animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show();
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({ opacity: 0 }, {
        step: function (now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50) + "%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({ 'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')' });
            next_fs.css({ 'left': left, 'opacity': opacity });
        },
        duration: 800,
        complete: function () {
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        },
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});
```

now all this behavior must be fired in regards of my ajax call that I have in a different .js:

```
$("#ToStepThree").click(function () {
    var valueParameter = $("#DocumentNumber").val();

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: 'Customer/ExistUserByDocument',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { document: valueParameter },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (exists)
        {
            alert(exists);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            alert("error");
        }

    });
});
```

So the idea here is that, if this Ajax returns true I need to override the behavior of the next, but if it is false then it should go to the next fieldset.

This is the HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="ToStepThree" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Continue &#8594" />
```

Any Idea how to achieve this?

Comment: why can't you just set `animating` in the ajax success callback based on response value?

Comment: As @charlietfl sais, you only have to call that first function if ajax response is true, so first thing you should do is to separate that function into a named one and call it depending on ajax result.

Comment: you mean to encapuslate the next click into a function? but if I do that the other buttons with class .next would not work unless I call the function right?